# Using variable value as for loop index

Tags: c#, for-loop, return

I have a code which contains 2 for loops:

```
for (int count = 0; list_Level[count] < list_Level[list_Level.Count]; count++)

        {
            for (int a = 0; list_Level[a] < Initial_Lvl; a++)
            {
                var dOpt = new DataGridObjectOpt();


                double Closest_Goallvl = list_Level.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - Initial_Lvl) < Math.Abs(y - Initial_Lvl) ? x : y);

                dOpt.ImageSource = new Uri(filePaths[a], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                dOpt.Level_Index = Initial_Lvl;
                dOpt.Level_Goal = goallvl;
                dOpt.Stage = 1;

                LOpt_Temp.Add(dOpt);

            }

            count = a;
            int best_Profit_Ind = LOpt_Temp.FindIndex(x => x.TotalCost == LOpt_Temp.Max(y => y.TotalCost));
            LOpt.Add(LOpt_Temp[best_Profit_Ind]);
            dataGridOpt.ItemsSource = LOpt;
        }
```

I want the loops to begin at 0, however once the inner loop ends for the first time and ends at a value of `a`, i want the outer loop to begin from this place now.

For example, first loop begins at 0, inner loop exits when a=6. Now i want count to start for 6 and not 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Before iterating again do `count+=a-1`.

Comment: when you do that, you run the risk of an `IndexOutOfRangeException` in the outer loop's condition (which is already obscure enough)

Comment: is there any option to avoid it mate?

Answer (score 0):

As @dcg mentioned, do count+=a-1 before iterating again. As @dlatikay mentioned, you could run into `IndexOutOfRangeException`. To avoid that, add and condition in the outer for loop. So that your final code looks something like this:

```
for (int count = 0; list_Level[count] < list_Level[list_Level.Count] && count < list_Level.Count; count++)
{
    for (int a = 0; list_Level[a] < Initial_Lvl; a++)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    count+=a-1

    //Your code
}
```

Notice the middle condition in the outer for loop. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
list_Level[count] < list_Level[list_Level.Count]
```

by using this condition you will get IndexOutOfRangeException you should use

```
list_Level[count] < list_Level[list_Level.Count - 1]
```

something like that.
on the other hand this may help you:

```
for (int count = 0; list_Level[count] < list_Level[list_Level.Count - 1] && count < list_Level.Count; count++){
      for (int a = 0; list_Level[a] < Initial_Lvl; a++)
      {
         //Your code
      }
      count = a-1;
      if(count  >= list_Level.Count)
      {
          break;
      }
      //Your code
```

}